# K-means function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have written a k-means function in Python to understand the methodology. I am trying to use this on a more complex dataset with a larger value for k, but it is running super slow. Does anyone have any recommendations for how I can improve this? I have provided code below, along with loading in an example dataset and applying the algorithm.

```
def Euc(x,y):
    return math.sqrt(sum([(a - b) ** 2 for a,b in zip(x,y)]))

def K_means(TE,k):
    Iteration = 0
    R = []
    O_a = []
    Epoch = 0
    Tol = 1
    Old_Tol = 2
    Tol_r = []
    start_time = time.time()
    mean_cl = [[random.uniform(TE.iloc[i].min(),TE.iloc[i].max()) for i in range(len(TE.columns))] for c in range(0,k)]
    for n in range(len(TE)):
        D = [Euc(TE.iloc[n].tolist(),mean_cl[c]) for c in range(0,k)]  
        O_a.append(D.index(min(D)))
    while(abs(Old_Tol - Tol) > 0.005):
        Old_Tol = Tol
        Epoch = Epoch + 1
        mean_cl = [TE.iloc[[j for j, x in enumerate(O_a) if x == i]].mean() for i in range(0,k)]
        N_a = []
        for n in range(len(TE)):
            Iteration = Iteration + 1
            D = [Euc(TE.iloc[n].tolist(),mean_cl[c]) for c in range(0,k)] 
            N_a.append(D.index(min(D)))
       Tol = np.mean([x != y for x,y in zip(O_a,N_a)])
        Tol_r.append(Tol)
        O_a = N_a
    R.append(time.time() - start_time)
    R.append(Tol_r)
    R.append(N_a)
    R.append(Iteration)
    return R

def load_Pima():
    url = "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/PRNN/pima.tr"
    Pima_training = pd.read_csv(url,sep = '\s+')
    url = "http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/PRNN/pima.te"
    Pima_testing = pd.read_csv(url,sep = '\s+')
    Pima_training = Pima_training.iloc[1:]
    Pima_testing = Pima_testing.iloc[1:]
    Pima_training.loc[:,"type"] = Pima_training.loc[:,"type"].apply(lambda x : 0 if x == 'Yes' else 1)
    Pima_testing.loc[:,"type"] = Pima_testing.loc[:,"type"].apply(lambda x : 0 if x == 'Yes' else 1)
    Features = Pima_training.loc[:,Pima_training.columns != "type"]
    Means = Features.mean()
    SDs = Features.std()
    for name in Features.columns:
        Pima_training[name] = (Pima_training[name]-Means[name])/SDs[name]
        Pima_testing[name] = (Pima_testing[name]-Means[name])/SDs[name]
    return Pima_training, Pima_testing

Pima_training, Pima_testing = load_Pima()

class_var = "type"
random.seed(2031)
k = 2
TE = Pima_testing
TE = TE.loc[:,TE.columns != class_var]
km = K_means(TE,k)
```

The function returns the runtime of the algorithm, the tolerance at each epoch (% of changes in cluster assignment), the final cluster assignments, and the total number of iterations. I have already removed four for loops, which has sped it up quite a bit. But I fear my lack of Python programming is holding me back from making this more efficient. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I tried to run this code, but I get this error: `NameError: name 'Euc' is not defined`. Can you include that function too?

Comment: Can you show the `Euc` function? One efficiency step would be to vectorize this and apply it to the whole dataframe `TE` at once instead of row by row.

Comment: Woops sorry guys. Added the "Euc" function now too.

Comment: Please do not edit the code after you have received a review, this violates our [question and answer policy](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) and everyone needs to be able to see the code that the answer(s) apply to. You can create a follow up question by asking a new question with the updated code and then making a link between the 2 question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can vectorize this at various points to apply arithmetic to the whole dataframe rather than row-by-row.

```
def min_euclidean(df, options):
    """ Returns the index of the series in iterable options for which df - row has minimum
    Euclidean distance """
    return pd.DataFrame(((df - series) ** 2).sum(axis=1, skipna=False) for series in options).idxmin()

def k_means(TE, k):
    iteration = 0
    epoch = 0
    tol = 1
    old_tol = 2
    tols = []
    start_time = time.time()
    mean_cl = [random.uniform(TE.min(), TE.max()) for _ in range(k)]
    o_a = min_euclidean(TE, mean_cl)
    while abs(old_tol - tol) > 0.005:
        old_tol = tol
        epoch += 1
        mean_cl = [TE[o_a == i].mean() for i in range(k)]
        n_a = min_euclidean(TE, mean_cl)
        iteration += len(TE)
        tol = (o_a != n_a).mean()
        tols.append(tol)
        o_a = n_a
    return time.time() - start_time, tols, n_a, iteration
```

Note that:

- wherever possible we work with Pandas series or dataframes instead of lists
- I calculate `mean_cl` as a list of Pandas series instead of a list of lists. This way we avoid iterating through the column or row indices of `TE`, which is slower. There might be some way to optimize this further by storing `mean_cl` as a dataframe, but I can't see an obvious way of working with it that way.
- there is no need to take the square root for the Euclidean distance - the indices associated with minimal distance will be the same working with the squared values
- `o_a` and `n_a` are also stored as series. We can then do `(o_a!= n_a).mean()` to calculate the disparity between them.
- The biggest optimization here is probably the `min_euclidean` function which calculates the square difference for the entire dataframe in an optimized way, rather than iterating through it.

[This](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6) may be a helpful explanation of vectorization. Working with Pandas series and dataframes in an optimal often involves a slightly different way of thinking than in regular Python.

EDIT: Here is a version using numpy instead of pandas. This fully vectorizes all the operations and is substantially faster again. It uses an optimization from this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64252529/567595).

```
def k_means(TE, k):
    epoch = 0
    tol = 1
    old_tol = 2
    tols = []
    start_time = time.time()
    te = np.array(TE)
    rows, columns = te.shape
    te3 = te[:, np.newaxis]  # 3d version of te for calculating euclidean more easily
    k_range = np.arange(k)[:, np.newaxis]
    mean_cl = np.random.uniform(te.min(axis=0), te.max(axis=0), size=(k, columns))
    o_a = np.nanargmin(((te3 - mean_cl) ** 2).sum(axis=2), axis=1)
    while abs(old_tol - tol) > 0.005:
        old_tol = tol
        epoch += 1
        m = o_a == k_range     # masks for each value in range 0 to k-1
        mean_cl = m.dot(te) / m.sum(1, keepdims=True)
        n_a = np.nanargmin(((te3 - mean_cl) ** 2).sum(axis=2), axis=1)
        tol = (o_a != n_a).mean()
        tols.append(tol)
        o_a = n_a
    return time.time() - start_time, tols, n_a, epoch * rows
```

Comment: Apologies there was a missing `.mean()` -- edited and it should return the same results now

Comment: Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: I have edited the answer as it was sometimes giving different results from the original: `skipna=False` is needed in the `min_euclidean` function for cases where there are one or more clusters to which no rows are assigned.